# How to make regular expression to allow optional prefix and suffix extraction

Tags: java, regex

As title described, the regular expression should serve the purpose on extract information by given string, prefix of the string (optional) and suffix of the string (optional)

So that

`prefix_group_1_suffix` returns `group_1` when prefix is 'prefix_' and suffix is `_suffix`

`prefix_group_1` returns `group_1` when prefix is 'prefix_' and suffix is `null`<-- my code can't handle this situation

`group_1_suffix` returns `group_1` when prefix is 'null' and suffix is `_suffix`

`group_1` returns `group_1` when prefix is 'null' and suffix is `null` <-- my code can't handle this situation

Here is my code, however I found it doesn't work when

```
    String itemName = "";
    String prefix = "TEST_";
    String suffix = "";
    String itemString = prefix + "item_1" + suffix;
    String prefix_quote = "".equals(prefix) ? "" : Pattern.quote(prefix);
    String suffix_quote = "".equals(suffix) ? "" : Pattern.quote(suffix);
    String regex = prefix_quote + "(.*?)" + suffix_quote;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(itemString);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        itemName = matcher.item(1);
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("itemString '"+itemString+"'");
    System.out.println("Prefix quote '"+prefix_quote+"'");
    System.out.println("Suffix quote '"+suffix_quote+"'");
    System.out.println("regex '"+regex+"'");
    System.out.println("itemName is '"+itemName+"'");
```

and here is the output

```
itemString 'TEST_item_1'
Prefix quote '\QTEST_\E'
Suffix quote ''
regex '\QTEST_\E(.*?)'
itemName is ''
```

But above code works well with for the other two conditions

Comment: Did you look at any tutorials on regex?

Comment: Well consider the two scenarios, prefix_group_1 and group_1_suffix. I believe prefix and suffix can be any text values. Then both patterns are same as A_B_C. How does a system say if A is a prefix and B_C is your data with suffix missing, or C is a suffix with A_B as your data with prefix missing. The system needs more information. Also, if your text is formatted with underscore, is there a specific reason why you need to work with Regex, why not just tokenize it to parse.

Comment: Why are you iterating over the matches? The way I understand your question, you can only have (at most).one match per string.

Comment: [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) doesn't have an `item()` method, so that code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code fails lies in the lazy quantifier `.*?`. It's priority is to match as little as possible, preferably the empty string, so it does just that. Therefore you need to anchor the regex to the start/end of the string and the possible prefix/suffix.

For that, you can use [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
String prefix = "TEST_";
String suffix = "";
String itemString = prefix + "item_1" + suffix;
String prefix_quote = "".equals(prefix) ? "^" : Pattern.quote(prefix);
String suffix_quote = "".equals(suffix) ? "$" : Pattern.quote(suffix);
String regex = "(?<=^|" + prefix_quote + ")(.*?)(?=$|" + suffix_quote + ")";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(itemString);
```

This will result in the regex

```
(?<=^|TEST_)item_1(?=$|$)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=    # Assert that it's possible to match before the current position
 ^      # either the start of the string
|       # or
 TEST_  # the prefix
)       # End of lookbehind
item_1  # Match "item_1"
(?=$|$) # Assert that it's possible to match after the current position
        # either the end of the string or the suffix (which is replaced
        # by the end of the string if empty. Of course that could be optimized
        # when constructing the regex, this is just a quick-and-dirty solution).
```

Comment: If the `^` and `$` anchors are appropriate at all, it means that the regex is for *matching*, not *finding*, so drop the anchors and simply call `matches()` instead of `find()`.

Comment: That wouldn't work because the lookaround assertions don't actually match the text; `.matches()` requires the entire string to be matched by the regex. Note that the anchors are inside the lookaround assertions, not at the start/end of the regex. I do think the OP needs to confirm that his goal is indeed matching, not finding.